# How to echo in variable url

Tags: php, wordpress, variables

I'm relatively new to php & was wondering if I can pass echo statement within variable. I have this in wordpress trying to retrieve profile picture using variable id to be able to integrate in wp comment section. Tried this.

```
$idd= author_details(get_the_ID());

$authordata = get_userdata( $idd );

$au=$authordata->display_name;

$authorAvatar = '<img src="http://www.example.com/photos/<?php echo getimg($au);?>" class="avatar user-1-avatar avatar-28 photo" width="40" height="40" alt="profile pic" >';
```

Here is the  result image url I'm getting:

```
http://www.example.com/photos/%3C?php%20echo%20getimg($au);?%3E
```

It's apparent that I cannot pass echo statement within variable, but the sad thing is I'm unable to find solution for this simple stuff.

Note: The code works perfectly when they are put outside variable.

Voluntary help will be highly appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: Please have a read up on [strings in PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php).

Answer (score 1):

You don't need the PHP tags in the middle.

```
$var = getimg($au);
$authorAvatar = '<img src="http://www.example.com/photos/'.$var.'" class="avatar user-1-avatar avatar-28 photo" width="40" height="40" alt="profile pic" >';
```

Comment: Thank you dude.. How quickly you responded without undermining someone's knowledge or potential..Love it!!!

Comment: No worries, can you accept the answer? :-)